# Search spotlight for iTunes music?

Tags: macos, itunes, high-sierra, spotlight

Can I play a song from spotlight?

Maybe not default Apple feature, but is there a flashlight plugin for this or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this natively.

Just open Spotlight as you normally would (e.g. use the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> shortcut) and start entering the name of the song. Spotlight will find it and you can just press <kbd>enter</kbd> to play it.

**Notes:**

- You don't need to have iTunes running at the time you conduct the Spotlight search, but you do have to have the song stored locally (i.e. not in iCloud), otherwise you'll get web search results etc instead of an iTunes result.
- You also have to ensure you have Music selected in the Search Results tab within Apple > System Preferences > Spotlight

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: nvm it's a thing I had to turn on in Preferences > Spotlight

Comment: No worries, it prompted me to add an additional note to my answer! :)